# Highcharts Datetime axis

Tags: jquery, datetime, highcharts, axis

im geting data for both x- and y-axis through php (from array) and "writing it down" in the series block in the format [x,y] like this:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Dat1',
            color: '#AA4643',
            yAxis: 0,
            data: [[Date.UTC(2013, 07, 10), 9],[Date.UTC(2013, 07, 11), 56],[Date.UTC(2013, 07, 12), 25],...],
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
          }, {
            name: 'Dat2',
            color: '#4572A7',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [[Date.UTC(2013, 07, 10), 9],[Date.UTC(2013, 07, 11), 22],[Date.UTC(2013, 07, 12), 8],...],
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
          }]
```

As you can see here the dates are for the month july, However in the chart the x-axis show the month august (maybe the actual month) instead of july!! Where is this coming from?

An Example can you see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8rysM/

How can solve it?

Comment: Months are starting from 0, i.e. 06 is July.

Comment: is there any setting to let it starting from 1?

Comment: I am not aware of such setting. You can go over your Date objects in javascript and just `setUTCMonth` as `getUTCMonth()-1`

Comment: can you give an example. When I try to set in the javascript I get `ReferenceError: getUTCMonth is not defined`

Comment: You can calculate inside date.utc -1 in month index or use formatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use formatter to implement correction of the month. 
One fix for `xAxis` to display correct month:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels : {
        formatter: function() {
            var myDate = new Date(this.value);
            var newDateMs = Date.UTC(myDate.getUTCFullYear(),myDate.getUTCMonth()-1,myDate.getUTCDate());   
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b',newDateMs);      
        }
    }    
}
```

And similar one for `tooltip`:

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
              var myDate = new Date(this.x);
              var newDateMs = Date.UTC(myDate.getUTCFullYear(),myDate.getUTCMonth()-1,myDate.getUTCDate());   
              return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', newDateMs) +': '+ this.y;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexpert/8rysM/2/)